# How to prove that $X$ is not rational $X = Z - \pi \times Y$ where $Y$ is rational , $Z$ is an integer, $\times$ means multiplication

Tags: rational-numbers

Excuse me for a silly question like this.
I am 60 years old retired engineer and
want to learn some basic math I di did not learn earlier.

I know an example where $(x + y\pi)$ can be an integer,
where $y$ is rational ,  * means multiplication
But how to prove the general case
if $x$ is always rational ,
always non-rational
or both depending upon the case.

Thanks

Comment: You have to exclude $Y=0$.  With that exclusion, then if your equation held we could evaluate $\pi$ as $\pi = \frac {Z-X}Y$ which would contradict the fact that $\pi$ is not rational.

Comment: Note:  your example had better have $Y=0$ or it can not be correct, for the same reason.

Comment: Multyplying a non zero rational number by a irrational number is irrrational. The additon of a rational number with an irrational is rational.

Comment: Thank you very much dear friends. I would like to evaluate each of the statements. Slow as I am due to my age, it may take a little time though. Thanks for encouraging me.

Comment: Hi lulu,
Thanks for your easy proof. I understood it.

Comment: Hello Ben,
Thanks. I am little confused with this statement below - is it a typo(_italics below_)?
"The additon of a rational number with an irrational is _rational_."
Addition rules,my guess should be :

1.  rational + irrational =irrational
2. irrational + irrational = **rational**  or irrational 
My original question ( already proof has been provided by lulu and M.Nestor )points to this case   irrational + irrational = **rational** ( under some constraints, may be )

Answer (score 0):

Suppose for a contradiction $x$ is rational. Then $x=a/b$ where $a,b$ are coprime integers and $b\neq0$.  Also assume $y=c/d$ for coprime integers $c$ and $d$, and furthermore assume $c$ is not zero (so $y$ is not zero). Then,
$$ x = z - \pi y $$
if and only if
$$ \frac{a}{b} = z - \pi \frac{c}{d} $$
Multiply by $bd$:
$$ ad = zbd - \pi cb $$
Then,
$$ \pi cb = zbd - ad $$
Divide by $cb$ (this is possible since both are nonzero):
$$ \pi = \frac{zbd-ad}{cb} $$
This implies that $\pi$ is rational which is a contradiction.

Comment: Great, I will understand the equations better than words.
I will revert back soon. Thanks a lot for showing me the way.

Comment: Thank you very much, Nestor.
It's beautiful, I never learnt this method of proof by **Contradiction.**
I think I shall utilize similar approach to prove few of my doubts regarding _multiplications of irrationals with irrational and rational_. I may come back to you in case of doubt. Have a nice day.